# UnsafeMutablePointer usage in Swift 3

Tags: uibezierpath, initializer, unsafemutablepointer

I am using the following extension for UIBezierPath:

```
extension UIBezierPath {

    var elements: [PathElement] {

        var pathElements = [PathElement]()

        withUnsafeMutablePointer(&pathElements) { elementsPointer in

            CGPathApply(CGPath, elementsPointer) { (userInfo, nextElementPointer) in

                let nextElement = PathElement(element: nextElementPointer.memory)

                let elementsPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<[PathElement]>(userInfo)

                elementsPointer.memory.append(nextElement)
            }
        }
        return pathElements
    }
}
```

This is from the site:

> https://oleb.net/blog/2015/06/c-callbacks-in-swift/

However, this breaks with Swift 3 for the following line:

```
let elementsPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<[PathElement]>(userInfo)
```

Following error is displayed:

```
Cannot invade initializer for type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<[PathElement]>' with an argument list of type '(UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)'
```

I understand that this is related to the change in Swift 3:`UnsafeRawPointerMigration`

> https://swift.org/migration-guide/se-0107-migrate.html

However, I am not quite sure the best way to port this to Swift 3.  Would you be able to provide some help in this regard w/ updated code for the above extension?

Answer (score 0):

I reached out Ole Begemann directly regarding this question.  He was very helpful and promptly provided updated code that works with Swift 3.  Sharing the same if someone else runs into the same issue as well.

This should work:

```
extension UIBezierPath {

    var elements: [PathElement] {

        var pathElements = [PathElement]()

        withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &pathElements) { elementsPointer in

            let rawElementsPointer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(elementsPointer)

            cgPath.apply(info: rawElementsPointer) { userInfo, nextElementPointer in

                let nextElement = PathElement(element: nextElementPointer.pointee)

                let elementsPointer = userInfo?.assumingMemoryBound(to: [PathElement].self)

                elementsPointer?.pointee.append(nextElement)
            }
        }

        return pathElements
    }
}
```

Comment: In Swift 4 , the trailing closure that starts with `elementsPointer` won't compile; error is "Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate". Xcode suggests adding this annotation: `elementsPointer -> @lvalue [Path Element]` but taking this suggestion just leads to more errors. Any hints?